# TURNING NETbeans hibernate and mysql to derby embedded

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, driver, derby

I am developing an application using Netbeans hibernate and MySQL and this works just fine. 
Switching backend to Derby Embedded database, hibernate cannot do reverse engineering.

**With the message:** `cannot access database with the configuration in "hibernate.cfg"`

**My configuration:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.default_schema">servlandDERBY</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:servlandDERBY</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
 </session-factory>
```

I have included the jar file javaDB in my project which includes derby.jar
Do I have to make any other settings or extra configurations in Netbeans?

Comment: My answer could help you ?

Answer (score 0):

**Both Network and Embedded**

**Java DB (Network)**

Property string:

```
<property
name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
</property>
```

Create a New Connection to test your DB inside Netbeans.

- A) Go to Services - Databases (right click) - New Connection
- B) try to create a new connection
- C) Drivers Derby OK ?
- D) an open connection

[image]

Set the correct settings

- A) Database URL
- B) Driver - **org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver**

[image]

**Java DB (Embedded)**

right click on - Java DB (Embedded) - Connect Using

[image]

- Fill the form out as described below
- Click Test Connection

[image]

Now you can see the new connection

[image]

Properties of the new connection !! Watch out for the database URL

[image]

Property string:

```
<property
 name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
</property>
<property
 name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/Administrator/.netbeans-derby/sample
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
```

If you get an error

that means
The Database is opened by embedded connection

[image]

that means
The Database is opened by network connection

[image]

Hope that helps.